# How to Get the list of Unsubscribed Emails from Mailchimp in C#?

Tags: list, mailchimp

Here is my code
  //private void GetUnsubscribers(string apikey, string MailChimpCampaignID)
    //{

```
//    campaignUnsubscribesInput input = new campaignUnsubscribesInput();
//    input.api_AccessType = PerceptiveMCAPI.EnumValues.AccessType.Serial;
//    input.api_CustomErrorMessages = true;
//    input.api_MethodType = PerceptiveMCAPI.EnumValues.MethodType.POST;
//    input.api_Validate = true;
//    input.api_OutputType = PerceptiveMCAPI.EnumValues.OutputType.XML;
//    input.parms.apikey = apikey;
//    input.parms.cid = MailChimpCampaignID;
//    campaignUnsubscribes unsubscribe = new campaignUnsubscribes();
//    campaignUnsubscribesOutput output = unsubscribe.Execute(input);

//    Unsubscribers.AddRange(output.result.data);
//    string unsubscriber = "0";
//    string[] unsubs;
//    foreach (listMembers list1 in output.result)
//    {
//        unsubscriber = list1.ToString();
//    }

//    string unsubscribers = Unsubscribers.Count.ToString();

//    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>alert('Unsubscribers::  '+ ' " + unsubscribers + " ');</script>");
//}
```

But the problem is, i am unable to pass campaign id to this function because i am creating a new campaign every time, so each time a new id is generated for campaign.
please help, As i am new in this line, so sorry in advance if there is something wrong in the code......................